# Uncertainty estimation in the input space

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, uncertainty

my input is an array between 0 and 1000 and the output is the corresponding system velocity. The input value is randomly generated (for instance by using the function in Python `random.randrange(0, 1000)`). The corresponding system velocity is then saved as the output.

Is there a way to estimate the uncertainty in my input space (0~1000) such as when the input area between 0 and 100 has not been applied to the system that it can define the area between 0 and 100 as "uncertain area" and can actually qunatify this "uncertainty"?

Comment: You have to translate this into English

Comment: @Aksakal, edited the post. Hope it is better comprehensible.

Comment: All of the uncertainty concerning your input is in the random.randrange() function.  I suggest reading the documentation on this function.  Does it generate uniformly distributed observations between 0 and 1,000?  Is the distribution perhaps some other type of scaled beta?  Is the support restricted to integers only?  You could generate 10,000 draws using the random.randrange() function and create a histogram to see what it is producing.